# unmatched left table records in a left join in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames, 'Students' DataFrame and 'Fee' DataFrame. The fee details of some of the students are missing in 'Fee' DataFrame. I would like to return the details of all students whose fee details are missing. The three fields 'Class', 'Section' and 'RollNo' form a unique combination.

```
Students = pd.DataFrame({
    'Class': [7, 7, 8],
    'Section': ['A', 'B', 'B'],
    'RollNo': [2, 3, 4],
    'Student': ['Ram', 'Rahim', 'Robert']
})

Fee = pd.DataFrame({
    'Class': [7, 7, 8],
    'Section': ['A', 'B', 'B'],
    'RollNo': [2, 2, 3],
    'Fee': [10, 20, 30]
})
```

---

```
Students

   Class  RollNo Section Student
0      7       2       A     Ram
1      7       3       B   Rahim
2      8       4       B  Robert
```

---

```
Fee

   Class  Fee  RollNo Section
0      7   10       2       A
1      7   20       2       B
2      8   30       3       B
```

Essentially, I would like to find the unmatched records from the left table when I do a left join between 'Students' and 'Fee' DataFrames based on 3 fields mentioned above. What is the simplest way to achieve this using **Pandas in Python**?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no `NaN`s in `Fee` column in `Fee` DataFrame use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) anf filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
df = pd.merge(Students, Fee, how='left')
print (df)
   Class  RollNo Section Student   Fee
0      7       2       A     Ram  10.0
1      7       3       B   Rahim   NaN
2      8       4       B  Robert   NaN

df1 = df[df['Fee'].isna()].drop('Fee', axis=1)
#for oldier versions of pandas
#df1 = df[df['Fee'].isnull()].drop('Fee', axis=1)
print (df1)
   Class  RollNo Section Student
1      7       3       B   Rahim
2      8       4       B  Robert
```

More general solution working with `NaN`s too add parameter `indicator` to `merge` and filter rows with `left_only`:

```
Fee = pd.DataFrame({'Class':[7,7,8],
                    'Section':['A','B','B'],
                    'RollNo':[2,2,3],
                    'Fee':[np.nan,20,30]})
print (Fee)
   Class   Fee  RollNo Section
0      7   NaN       2       A
1      7  20.0       2       B
2      8  30.0       3       B

df = pd.merge(Students, Fee, how='left', indicator=True)
print (df)
   Class  RollNo Section Student  Fee     _merge
0      7       2       A     Ram  NaN       both
1      7       3       B   Rahim  NaN  left_only
2      8       4       B  Robert  NaN  left_only

df1 = df[df['_merge'].eq('left_only')].drop(['Fee','_merge'], axis=1)
print (df1)
   Class  RollNo Section Student
1      7       3       B   Rahim
2      8       4       B  Robert
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having a bit of fun with this concept.

### Option 1

1. use `pandas.concat` with the `keys` argument
2. ensure that the `Students`s portion gets a value of `'stu'` for the first level of the resulting `MultiIndex`.
3. use `pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates` with the argument `keep=False` to drop all duplication.
4. focus on **just** the `Students` portion by using `loc`.

---

```
catted = pd.concat([Students, Fee], keys=['stu', 'fee'])
dropped = catted.drop_duplicates(['Class', 'RollNo', 'Section'], keep=False)
index = dropped.loc['stu'].index

Students.loc[index]

   Class  RollNo Section Student
1      7       3       B   Rahim
2      8       4       B  Robert
```

---

### Option 2

Use sets on list of tuples, take a difference and merge with an contrived dataframe.

```
cols = ['Class', 'RollNo', 'Section']
s = set(map(tuple, Students[cols].values))
f = set(map(tuple, Fee[cols].values))

Students.merge(pd.DataFrame(list(s - f), columns=cols))

   Class  RollNo Section Student
0      7       3       B   Rahim
1      8       4       B  Robert
```