# Pandas drop subset of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume we have `df` and `df_drop`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [1,1,1]})
df_drop = df[df.A==df.B]
```

I want to delete `df_drop` from `df` without using the explicit conditions used when creating `df_drop`. I.e. I'm not after the solution `df[df.A!=df.B]`, but would like to, basically, take `df` minus `df_drop` somehow. Hopes this is clear enough. Otherwise happy to elaborate!

Comment: @Datanovice that's not the same thing though...

Comment: @JonClements you are right, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Basically a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49838956/unmatched-left-table-records-in-a-left-join-in-pandas), but then `how='outer'` instead of `left`. What you want is called an `unmatch join`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) both dataframes setting `indicator=True` and drop those columns where the indicator column is `both`:

```
out = pd.merge(df,df_drop, how='outer', indicator=True)
out[out._merge.ne('both')].drop('_merge',1)

   A  B
1  2  1
2  3  1
```

---

Or as jon clements points out, if checking by index is enough, you could simply use:

```
df.drop(df_drop.index)
```

Comment: Depending how generic this is supposed to be - given the OP's sample code, then: `df.drop(df_drop.index)` would also be an option

Comment: Yes that might just do depending on what OP wants :) updated with ur suggestion @jon

Comment: Though I'm guessing that since op is aware of the simple solution to this in the terms it was asked, I guess they want the more general approach of removing equal rows @jon

Comment: I think the first solution is great. `df.drop(df_drop.index)` would actually do the work in my real case as well, but I was indeed after a more general approach! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `drop_duplicates` works because the test criteria is the equality of two rows.

More generally, you can use `loc` to find the rows that meet or do not meet the specified criteria.

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 50, 100)
b = np.random.randint(1, 50, 100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b})
criteria = df.a > 2 * df.b
df.loc[criteria, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this maybe:

```
In [1468]: pd.concat([df, df_drop]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)                                                                                                                                             
Out[1468]: 
   A  B
1  2  1
2  3  1
```